# Firefox: How to run HTML FILES in two separate windows

Tags: firefox, browser

I have two HTML FILES , when I click on those HTML Files , they run in the same window of Mozilla Firefox

Is it possible to run them separately in two windows of Firefox?

Comment: You have 2 HTML files where? On your computer?

Comment: Looks like somebody removed the [tag:JavaScript] tag from the question.
@Kiran may want to know how you can open **links** in a new window instead of a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click and drag one of the tabs away from the window. This will create a new window for that tab.

Answer (score 1):

To have files on your file system opened in a new window instead of a new tab, go to *Firefox* > *Options* > *Tabs* and uncheck *Open new windows in a new tab*.

If you're trying to do this from a web page link, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/68jd2/1/) should work:

```
link.onclick=function(evt){
    window.open('http://example.com','windowName','menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes,personalbar=yes');

    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

You can find more information about [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/window.open) at the Mozilla Developer wiki.